# how do I create a public String from a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, encryption, compiler-errors

I'm creating an encryption method that takes input from a JTextArea, and I'm getting an error saying:

'Illegal modifier for parameter input; only final is permitted'

I have gone through many documentation websites and other articles, and I have found nothing. Here is my near-complete code:

```
Package lake. RAMBIT7;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class RAMBIT7 implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    RAMBIT7 window = new RAMBIT7();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public RAMBIT7() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 600); //1024x768, 800x600
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("RAMBIT7 Encryption Software 1.0.0");
        frame.setResizable(false);

        /**
         * 'Encrypt' and 'Decrypt' buttons
         */

        JButton encrypt = new JButton("Encrypt");
        encrypt.addActionListener(this);
        JButton decrypt = new JButton("Decrypt");
        decrypt.addActionListener(this);

        /**
         * JMenuBar
         */

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
        JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
        JMenuItem license = new JMenuItem("License");
        JMenuItem close = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        file.add(close);
        help.add(about);
        help.add(license);
        bar.add(file);
        bar.add(help);
        about.addActionListener(this);
        license.addActionListener(this);
        close.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        /**
         * Text and input related stuff
         */
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[69px][71px,grow][]", "[23px][35.00][200px][][grow][]"));
        frame.getContentPane().add(encrypt, "cell 0 0,alignx left,aligny top");
        frame.getContentPane().add(decrypt, "cell 2 0,alignx right,aligny top");
        JLabel lblCopyTextIn = new JLabel("Copy Text in here.");//JLabel
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblCopyTextIn, "cell 1 1");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, "cell 0 2 3 1,grow");
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();//JTextArea
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
        JLabel lblOutputTextIn = new JLabel("Output text in RAMBIT7 encryption");//JLabel
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblOutputTextIn, "cell 1 3");
        JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane_1, "cell 0 4 3 1,grow");
        JTextArea textArea_1 = new JTextArea();//JTextArea_1
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(textArea_1);
        textArea_1.setEditable(false);
        textArea_1.setLineWrap(true);
        JLabel lblRambitEncryptionMethod = new JLabel("RAMBIT7 Encryption Method"); //JLabel
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblRambitEncryptionMethod, "cell 1 5");

        public String input_0 = textArea.getText();//Error here


    }



    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = e.getActionCommand();
        if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt")) {
            System.out.println("Begin RAMBIT7 encryption.");
            encryptRAMBIT7(input);
        } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("decrypt")) {
            System.out.println("Begin RAMBIT7 decryption.");
            decryptRAMBIT7(input);
        } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("about")) {
            System.out.println("Opening Program Specs...");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "RAMBIT7 v1.0.0");
            System.out.println("Program Specs Closed.");
        } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("license")) {
            System.out.println("Opening License...");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You may not sell this program or say that any part of the code is yours.");
            System.out.println("License closed.");
        } else if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Why, oh WHY CRUEL WORLD does that person have to close me?! I'm\na living thing too! Or maybe I'm an emotionless pig! NOOOOOOOO!");
            System.exit(3);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Declare    `public String input_0` as a class member

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to re-think your structure a bit:

- Even if you could get the String out of the JTextArea on creation time, it would not help you one bit. When the JTextArea changes its display text, that String will not change since Strings are invariants.
- Likewise a String field would not help, not unless it was dynamically bound to the JTextArea via a DocumentListener or something similar.
- Instead make the JTextArea a private field and extract its String when needed.
- If other classes need the text, then create a public method `public String getTextAreaText()` and return the text held by the JTextArea in that method.

---

```
public class RAMBIT7 implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea();

    // ....

   private void initialize() {

        // .....

        // JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();//JTextArea
        scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);
```

and elsewhere:

```
    if(a.equalsIgnoreCase("encrypt")) {
        System.out.println("Begin RAMBIT7 encryption.");
        encryptRAMBIT7(textarea.getText());
```

Comment: @user185164: you're not declaring the JTextArea in the **class** like I'm doing above. Please look carefully where it is being declared, right below your JFrame variable. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't use the `public` keyword inside a method. Visibility modifiers are used to determine what members of each object can be accessed from outside, by other objects or classes. Things you declare inside of a method are not members of a class, but rather things that only exist in that method, so visibility modifiers make no sense there.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String input_0 = textArea.getText();
```

Any variable declared inside a function is local to that function. Outside world don't know about that variable but the function itself. hence, access modifier `public`, `private` or `protected` are not applicable to local instance variable, such as `input_0` here which is local to `initialize()`. Again, this code, is inside `initialize()` function, which is responsible for initializing your GUI component,  creating them and adding them to the container, user input is yet to happen, so reading the text content of `textArea` is meaning less.